# Could not load defaultProptypes in Select - Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, next.js, react-redux-form

could you help with the problem please? I am using ANT Design in next.js and I am unable to load list which is defined in default `Proptypes.`isSelectOptGroup of undefined - is the message that I get always. 
So basically renderSelectoptions(Items) is the function that accepts array of Items and after that should be showed on screen. But That Did not happen.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Select as AntSelect, Option as AntOption } from './Select'
import FormItem from '../FormItem'
import Form from '../Form'


const propTypes = {
  // onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  form: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  items: PropTypes.array,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  options: PropTypes.object,
};

const defaultProps = {
  items: [
    {
      key: 1,
      value: 360,
      label: 'RSD'
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: 460,
      label: 'EuR'
    }
  ],
  name: 'hello',
  placeholder: 'RSD',
  label: 'Currency',
  options: { rules: [{ message: 'Please chose currency!' }] }
};

class Select extends PureComponent {
  handleSelectChange = (value) => {
    const { /*onChange,*/ form, name } = this.props
    form.setFieldsValue({
      [name]: value,
    });

    // onChange(value)
  }

  renderSelectOptions = items => items.map(item => (
    <AntOption key={item.key} value={item.value}>{item.label}</AntOption>))

  render() {
    const { name, label, placeholder, items, options, form } = this.props;
    return (
      <Form>
        <FormItem label={label}>
          { form.getFieldDecorator(name, { ...options })(
            <AntSelect
              size="large"
              placeholder={placeholder}
              onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
            >
              {items && this.renderSelectOptions(items)}
            </AntSelect>
          )}
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

Select.defaultProps = defaultProps;
Select.propTypes = propTypes;

const WrapperSelect = Form.create()(Select);

export default WrapperSelect;
```

Comment: It reads like this should function okay. Looking at the Ant Design issues on Github it looks like an issue with the current version. Roll back to .12? https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/7221

Comment: Actually, Airbnb way of importing did not work well. Had to disable that line. But thanks @stef! :)